# adding a search bar and search display controller on tableview in Storyboard?

Tags: tableview, searchbar

How do you add the search bar and search display controller on tableview or view Controller on storyboard?

When I add the search bar and search display controller on the tableview and run the app, the search bar does not auto layout to the tableview (parts of the right side is not showing) and when i click on the search bar in the iOS simulator, it crashes.
But when I add the search bar and search display controller on the table View Controller, it works perfectly fine.

What am I doing wrong?